# Property 'connected' does not exist on type 'Namespace<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, any>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, socket.io, disconnect

When I try to run the following code:

```
const endMeeting = async (meeting_id: string, socket: Socket, meeting_server: Server, payload: any) => {
    const { user_id } = payload.data;
    broadcastUsers(meeting_id, socket, meeting_server, {
        type: MeetingPayloadEnum.MEETING_ENDED,
        data: { user_id }
    });

    let users: IUser[] = await Meetings.getAllMeetingUsers(toBinaryUUID(meeting_id));
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let user = users[i];
        meeting_server.sockets.connected[user.socket_id].disconnect;
    }
}
```

It gives me this error message at the last line of the code:

> Property 'connected' does not exist on type
> 'Namespace<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap,
> any>'.

It seems the code is a little bit outdated and the `socket.io` works another way now, but I am not sure how? How should I update this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connected property is no longer available on the sockets property of the Namespace object in the latest version of Socket.IO. Instead, you can use the `sockets.sockets` property to get a map of all connected sockets, and then use the get method to retrieve a specific socket by its ID. Try this code:

```
const endMeeting = async (meeting_id: string, socket: Socket, meeting_server: 
Server, payload: any) => {
  const { user_id } = payload.data;
  broadcastUsers(meeting_id, socket, meeting_server, {
    type: MeetingPayloadEnum.MEETING_ENDED,
    data: { user_id }
  });

  let users: IUser[] = await 
  Meetings.getAllMeetingUsers(toBinaryUUID(meeting_id));
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let user = users[i];
    meeting_server.sockets.sockets.get(user.socket_id)?.disconnect();
  }
}
```

You can use the optional chaining operator (`?.`) to handle cases where the socket with the specified ID does not exist in the map (for example, if the user has already disconnected).